# Attach long text file to sql database

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

In my website there are name of Authors with their images. How can I add their biography to the database?
The biography is long text.

Comment: Use a column of type `varchar(max)` (or `nvarchar(max)` if you need to support Unicode). That's good for 2 GB of text - that's the entire Leo Tolstoj's *War and Peace* over 150 times over!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp LONGTEXT or just hold the file

Comment: If the biography contain some image I think that you must use some BLOB fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `biography` field data type `VARCHAR(MAX)` to store large text data.

Answer (score 0):

Varchar(max) is good to store large data file but if you are using SQL Server 2008 and above then I would explore an option called "File Stream" which allows you to store actual files outside of SQL Server but still can be easily maintained and accessed withing SQL Server.
This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695918.aspx) should give you head start about this great feature.